# How do I automate my javascript game to ask for a name and enter a url for my dreamlo leaderboard?

Tags: javascript, leaderboard

I have a javascript snake game on my site. I have a leaderboard from a site called http://dreamlo.com. It uses and http get to record scores. How can I automate it in Javascript? Here is the game download: https://github.com/patorjk/JavaScript-Snake

Comment: Hey there, welcome to Stack Overflow. I'd recommend editing your question to include relevant code, what you've tried so far, and a more accurate description of what you hope to accomplish. (automate it to do what?)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somehow very unspecific. Could you provide more information?

From what I know, you might try to use [setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) and fetch the leaderboard every x second or after new results has been sent to the leaderboard.